# fgetcsv() returns "true" for each line

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I am having a problem with php fgetcsv() method. I can only get the value "1" instead of an array for each line. Here is the code:

```
$row = 0;
$teststring='';
$handle = fopen($savepath,'r');
if($handle!==FALSE){
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,2000,'|')!==FALSE)){        //I am using '|' as the delimiter
        echo (string)$data;
        if($row!=0){
            foreach($data as $d){
                array_push($result['added'],$d);
            }
        }
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

I tested a 3-line csv file and the result will be "111". Of course there is no value in array $result['added']. Could any body know what is going on? Thank you.

Comment: I'll bet that the `!==` is evaluating first and the result is going into `$data`...

Comment: Hey, you are right! That's a good point. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Order of operations!

```
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,2000,'|')!==FALSE)){
```

PHP is interpreting this line as:

- Call `fgetcsv`
- Without casting, compare it to boolean `false`
- Assign the result of this comparison to `$data`

This isn't what you want.  Your parens are misplaced, you want the last one *before* the comparison:

```
while( ($data = fgetcsv($handle,2000,'|')) !== FALSE ){
```

I've added extra spaces to make the change more obvious.

Comment: Despite how your explanation is correct and is how PHP works,
The PHP syntax is actually misleading of the order of operations, and is inconsistent to how other calls of PHP works: The syntax suggests order of operations is fgetcsv, assign it to `$data`, and use that value to evaluate boolean as directed by the `while` keyword - just like how an actual variable that isn't a boolean gets evaluated as a boolean but doesn't get changed. Just another reason why PHP is garbage - all kinds of inconsistent, counterintuitive gotchas.

Comment: @ahnbizcad Oh?  Are there languages that would read the form `$foo = bar() != $baz` as anything other than `$foo = ( bar() != $baz )`?